# failing to add a close button into a jquery load function modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal box that loads a full PHP page using the jQuery `load()` method,
I was wondering how can I add a close button that close to the modal after the call and refresh the load request every recall to the function.

the code:

```
$('body').on('click','#more',function(){

        var i = $(this).data("info");
        $('body').append("<div id='modal_box'></div>");
        $('#modal_box').load('post.php?info='+i);
    });
```

Comment: Hint: Go to the documentation of [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and look at the `complete` argument.

Comment: @nem035 any more hints?